# Scripting language on Windows and Unix

Tags: windows, unix, scripting-language

I need to write a script that handle files. Its aim is to open and copy some sections from the file, in a binary context. 
The problem is I need to run it on both Windows and Unix.

Is there a scripting language that can handle both operating systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python](http://www.python.org) runs on both. The Windows version doesn't even need cygwin. If you have cygwin, then you can also use bash script.

Comment: Does Python also deals with internals issues, like services on windows and for instance domain at unix ?

Comment: You can add the [win32 extensions](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html), a separate package, that provides access to almost all of Windows stuff. You can even create services with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install a scripting language such as [Python](http://www.python.org/) or [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) and use it on both systems.

Alternatively, install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) on Windows, which will allow you to run a Bash shell under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org) also runs on both systems just fine and has support for manipulating paths for both worlds. There's a nice [installer for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and most Linux distros also ship it in their default installation.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used Tcl across Unix and Windows; you can find more information [here](http://www.tcl.tk/) and [here](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl?gclid=CLCG4-OSmacCFdERfAodgzW4cg).

Answer (score 0):

The command shell "bash", native on Unices, is also available on Windows.